# Python, TK Entry field validation

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

So I have a few entry fields where users are required to input the figures they require.

I have created a validation rule to prevent people from entering anything other than digits, and I inserted a default value of 0 just for the sake of the calculation.

The issue is that now the fields wont allow the figures in it to be cleared before entering any further digits, for example if the fields has a '0' in it, you would have to type 0123 and then delete the 0 to get 123, and if you wanted to change 123 you could only delete the 2 and the 3, you would have to type it and then delete the initial figure again.

Anyone know why this is happening?

```
vcmd = (root.register(self.validate),
            '%d', '%i', '%P', '%s', '%S', '%v', '%V', '%W') 

def validate(self, action, index, value_if_allowed, 
                   prior_value, text, validation_type, trigger_type, widget_name):
    if text in '0123456789.-+*':
        try:
            float(value_if_allowed)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False
    else:
        return False
```

I look forward to your responses, I will regularly refresh this page for the next 6 hours until I come to a conclusion!

Lewis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you can't convert a empty string to a float.

If you want to empty the entry, your `value_if_allowed` refers to `""`. This passes the `if` comparison but fails in the `try` clause.

You can add a simple test like this inside the existing `if` clause:

```
if not value_if_allowed:
    return True
```

By the way, it does not make sense to allow `".-+*"` as strings, as they would fail the convertation to float, too.

Comment: thanks for the advice ive removed those unnecessary charecters, after altering the If statement and including yours, unfortunately i still have a continued issue where i cannot have the field blank after deleting a digit in the field.

Comment: You shouldn't have this issue. Where did you put the if clause? Bryan's example includes this in a variation, too.

Comment: i did it like this:-

    def validate(self, action, index, value_if_allowed, 
                       prior_value, text, validation_type, trigger_type, widget_name):
        if text in '0123456789* ':
            try:
                float(value_if_allowed)
                return True
            except ValueError:
                return False
        if not value_if_allowed:
            return True
        else:
            return False

Comment: yeah, the thing is that you have to insert this if clause *before* everything else. It makes sense, if you think about it ;)

Comment: hahahahhahaha, so did i tell you that im a retard? literally mentally challenged, thankyou, that works wonderfully. I learned enough to make a full blown program in 2 weeks and i guess i must have skipped some basic knowledge :P

Answer (score 3):

It is happening because `""` isn't a valid float in python.

The solution is simple: if you want to allow an empty string, test for an empty string, and return True if the string is empty:

```
def validate(...):
    if (value_if_allowed == ""):
        return True
    ...
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesnt seem to work either :( im not sure why this is happening.

Comment: See comment on my answer; probably related to the placing of the clause ;)